# How to create a pairs-plot (matrix-like plot) with `grid`?

Tags: r, r-grid

I'm trying my first steps *purely* in `grid`. As an exercise, I would like to create a pairs plot (similar to `pairs()`) purely based on `grid`. The function `myplotGrob` below should create the grid object (grob; or gTree) and return the object.

I'm not sure
what's the best way to continue. Which units should one use? (tried `"null"`, too)
Is `frameGrob` meant to set up the layout? (this is what I understood from Paul Murrell's book) How do I have to choose/adjust the viewports such that I get the desired plot (so far, I only see a mess) Is the layout meant to be set up beforehand or is it better to just step-by-step "concatenate" additional panels to get the (4, 4) plot matrix?

```
require(grid)
require(mvtnorm)

set.seed(271)
X <- rmvnorm(1000, mean=1:4, sigma=diag(4:1)) # goal: draw this in a pairs plot

## auxiliary function
panel <- function(x, y) pointsGrob(x=x, y=y, name="panel", gp=gpar(), vp=NULL)

## creates and returns a gTree (class)
myplotGrob <- function(X, name=NULL, gp=NULL, vp=NULL)
{
    ## x-axis grob

    ## y-axis grob

    ## ...

    ## set up layout
    layout <- grid.layout(4, 4, # (4, 4) matrix
                          widths=rep(0.25, 4), heights=rep(0.25, 4),
                          default.units="npc")
    ## pushViewport(viewport(layout=layout)) # required???

    all <- frameGrob(layout=layout) # produces a gTree without children
    for(i in 1:4) {
        for(j in 1:4) {
            ## group grobs together
            gt <- gTree(X,
                        children=gList(panel(X[,i], X[,j])),
                        name=name, gp=gp, vp=vp, cl="myplotGrob")
            all <- placeGrob(all, gt, row=i, col=j)
        }
    }
    all
}

## draw the gTree
grid.myplot <- function(...) grid.draw(myplotGrob(...))

## call
grid.myplot(X)
```

**UPDATE**

As it was asked for, here is the design/layout of the original problem I have in mind (the above would have only been a minimal/learning example). The units in cm were just for me (they should be 'relative' in the end). Of course, the number of panels may vary. I would like all parts to be grid *objects*, so that the function which creates the graphic will return an object (without printing/drawing). This way, each part can be modified afterwards. The graphic should display results from an array of dimension 5 (or less): one dimension is displayed in the row panels [`row.vars`], one in the column panels [`col.vars`], one on the x axis of each panel [`xvar`], and each panel can contain 2 different dimensions of the array (differing by color and line type) [I used `d` and `n` in the drawing]. If course, if the array is four-dimensional, then row 8 of the above design should be missing. I can construct the layout via grid, but the whole question is how to continue from there. That's what I wanted to express with my "minimal example" above.

[image]

Comment: my advice: don't use frameGrobs and co; they're incredibly slow, and not very useful. The gtable package offers a much nicer alternative, in my opinion.

Comment: also, why do you want to reinvent what lattice and ggplot2 already do so well? Do you have a specific feature in mind?

Comment: Hi Baptiste, thanks for helping. Yes, we have (actually several) new features in mind. Ideally, we don't want to depend on another package (except `grid`), that's why we start from scratch (and it's also good to learn `grid`, so we take it as an exercise :-) ). If not using `frameGrobs` (which is what I understood from Paul's book the way to go), what else shall we use? Ideally, I just would like to see a minimal (but working) example of how to do it with grid.

Comment: `grid.multipanel()` can give you some ideas, I guess. Unless you describe more precisely what features you want to have in your target plot (regarding axes, spacing between panels, legend, strips, multiple layers of data, ...), it's gonna be difficult to give a meaningful answer. Draw it, if you can. There are many different ways to produce a plot, and it's not an easy task to come up with an optimal design (that's probably why every plotting program seems to reinvent the wheel).

Comment: Hi Baptiste, I have a very clear design drawn (by hand) today. I can scan it tomorrow and put it up.

Comment: Hi Baptiste, I added the design. I'm looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: my suggestion would be to study carefully what pieces of code you can borrow from other packages; grid itself offers very little to make complex plots, and that difficult problem has already been solved *twice*.

Comment: @baptiste I disagree. ggplot2 and lattice does not solve everybody's problem, some user may still want deeper control of their graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can divide the task in two main parts, like the basic examples in `grid.panel()` and `grid.multipanel()`

1- build a function that will produce a single panel, returned as a gTree. You need to figure out all the parameters, i.e. limits, axes, colours, shapes, grid, coordinates, ... You might end up rewriting lattice panel functions and axes,

```
grid.newpage()
grid::grid.panel(vp=viewport(width=0.8, height=0.8))
```

[image]

2- assemble the panels in a layout. This is *much* easier (and cleaner) with gtable,

```
library(gtable)

grid.newpage()
lg <- replicate(16, grobTree(rectGrob(), pointsGrob()), simplify=FALSE)

gt <- gtable_matrix("pairs", grobs=matrix(lg, ncol=4),
                    widths=unit(rep(1, 4), "null"),
                    heights=unit(rep(1, 4), "null"))

gt <- gtable_add_col_space(gt, width=unit(0.5,"line"))
gt <- gtable_add_row_space(gt, height=unit(0.5,"line"))
gt <- gtable_add_padding(gt, padding=unit(1,"line"))

grid.draw(gt)
```

If you want to build everything from scratch, here too you'll end up having to reinvent a good portion of gtable, I reckon.

[image]

Comment: Nice that you saw the "2-step" approach, that's exactly what I am looking for. Ideally, the panel function is provided by the user (e.g., a box plot or x-y plot). The basic matrix-like structure is then put around it. Indeed, `gtable` looks clean. It seems I have to carefully think about it. Let me accept the answer for now and then come back with follow-up questions in case we encounter them (I'm sure we will :-) ). Thanks very much, I somehow knew it would be good to ask experts first before really starting this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt similar to `grid.multipanel()` but returning a gTree, and more specific to your pairs plot,

```
require(grid)
require(mvtnorm)

set.seed(271)
X <- rmvnorm(100, mean=1:4, sigma=diag(4:1)) # goal: draw this in a pairs plot

panelGrob <- function(x=runif(10, -10, 10), y=runif(10, -10, 100), ...,
  xlim = range(x), ylim=range(y),
  axis.x=TRUE, axis.y=TRUE){
  xx <- pretty(x) ; yy <- pretty(y)
  xx <- xx[xx <= xlim[2] & xx >= xlim[1]]
  yy <- yy[yy <= ylim[2] & yy >= ylim[1]]

  r <- rectGrob()
  dvp <- dataViewport(xData=xx, yData=yy)
  p <- pointsGrob(x, y, pch=".", gp=gpar(col="red"), default.units="native",
                  vp = dvp)

  ax <- if(axis.x) xaxisGrob(at=xx, vp=dvp) else nullGrob()
  ay <- if(axis.y) yaxisGrob(at=yy, vp=dvp) else nullGrob()

  grobTree(r, ax, ay, p, ...)
}

grid.panel <- function(...)
  grid.draw(panelGrob(...))

grid.newpage()
grid.panel(vp=viewport(width=0.8, height=0.8))


pairsGrob <- function(X, ..., name=NULL, gp=NULL, vp=NULL){

  N <- NCOL(X)
  layout <- grid.layout(N+1, N+1, 
                        widths=unit(c(2, rep(1, N)), c("lines", rep("null", N))), 
                        heights = unit(c(rep(1, N), 2), c(rep("null", N), "lines")))


  wrap <- function(ii, jj, ...){
    panelGrob(X[,ii], X[,jj], ..., axis.x= ii == N, axis.y = jj == 1,
              vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=ii, layout.pos.col=jj+1))
  }

  rowcol <- expand.grid(ii=seq_len(N), jj=seq_len(N))
  gl <- mapply(wrap, ii=rowcol[,"ii"], jj=rowcol[,"jj"], MoreArgs=list(...),
               SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

  gTree(children=do.call(gList, gl), vp=viewport(layout=layout))
}

grid.pairs <- function(...) grid.draw(pairsGrob(...))

grid.newpage()
grid.pairs(X, xlim=c(-10,10), ylim=c(-10,10))
```

[image]

Many problems are already apparent: i) it's cumbersome to add spacings in the layout, keeping track of the right viewports; ii) most parameters of the panel function are hard-wired (point shape, colour, grid, axis labels, ...), be prepared for an explosion in complexity, as in `args(lattice::panel.xyplot)`; iii) the range of the axes should match across one row / column, which requires some thought about splitting the data properly in groups (facetting in ggplot2 or lattice); iv) the legend is yet another thing to reinvent in grid; v) ...

Comment: Dear Baptiste, thanks very much, this is all interesting to learn. We have the main plot according to the above design already in non-grid form, and, indeed, exactly faced the "explosion" problem of the tons of things the user may want to have.... Our idea was to make the function return a `gTree` so that the user can still modify it if required.